# Laravel authorization for Broadcast channels not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to integrate chat into a webapp using Laravel 5.4 (backend) and Angular 2 (frontend). I have a unqiue Broadcast channel that emits a message to a user. Each user has their own channel which is `chat-{uuid}` with `uuid` being a unique ID in a chat table which also stores the `userID` of the user who can access that channel. The problem is that the Authorization callback is never called so any user can access the channel if they know the `uuid`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

channels.php

```
// This authorization is never called 
Broadcast::channel('chat-{uuid}', function ($user, $uuid) {
    return false; 
});
```

NewMessage.php event

```
protected     $message;

public function __construct($message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
}

protected function prepareData()
{
    return [
        'chatID'                => $this->message->chatID,
        'userID'                => $this->message->builderID,
        'message'               => $this->message->message,
        ];

}

public function broadcastWith()
{
    return [
        'message' => $this->prepareData(),
    ];
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'new.message';
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat-'.$this->message->chatID);
}
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes( [ 'middleware' => [ 'api', 'auth.jwt' ] ] );
    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

Connecting to the broadchannel on the frontend (Messages are being recieved)

Component.ts

```
  window['Echo'] = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://app.test:6001',
    auth:
      {
        headers:
          {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.jwt
          }
      }
  });

window['Echo'].private(`chat-${this.chatUUID}`)
  .listen(".new.message", (data) => {
    this.messages.data.push(data.message);
  });
```

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: Please post the solution you found

Comment: I never was able to get it to work. I used one signal instead

Comment: did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is not on programming side but related to your web server configuration (or web socket server). I think you always got private channel authenticated but not through `/broadcusting/auth` simple because response gives you 200 code. As you can see in [laravel-echo-server sourse](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/blob/master/src/channels/private-channel.ts#L102) channels get authentication residually. So, your `routes/channels` may not be involved to the process. Furthermore if you exclude `BroadcastServiceProvider` from the configuration perhaps you will get private channel being authenticated anyway.

If everything indicated like that I would suggest take a look to the web-server configuration especially if you use SSL.[Alternative SSL implementation](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#alternative-ssl-implementation) and `laravel-echo-server.json` of course.